# D3 raise and lower svg element in firefox is not working

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I have a big SVG with several shapes like `rects, paths, lines, polylines`, etc exported from Adobe Illustrator. To break down the problem I will only use two rects, but keep in mind that I need a general solution.

The SVG looks like that:

```
<svg id="mysvg" class="test" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 3896 2696.1">
  <g id="B2">
    <rect class="cls-7" x="1300" y="500" width="100" height="500"/>
  </g>
  <g id="B3">
    <rect class="cls-7" x="1400" y="500" width="300" height="500"/>
  </g>
  </svg>
```

Some of the shapes are aligned to each other. I want to change the `fill` and `stroke` of the elements on `hover`.

Here is the very basic CSS

```
#mysvg > g:hover > *{
    fill: #f2f9fa !important;
    stroke: #29b1cc !important;
    stroke-width: 10px !important;
}

#mysvg > g {
  fill: #dfe5e6;
  stroke: #414d4d;
  stroke-width: 10px;
}
```

Until now this works both on Chrome and Firefox. As the `z-index` in SVG´s depends on the order in my HTML the right rect is on top of the left one. So if i hover over the left one the stroke won´t change to blue.

Therefore I am using `D3` to push the current element in front of everything. And here I run into problems in Firefox.

```
  <script>
    var svg = d3.select('#mysvg')
    svg.selectAll("g").on("mouseover", function(){
      d3.select(this).raise()

    });

</script>
```

I have to move my mouse twice into a buidling to fill it. On Chrome everything workes fine.

If i add following to my code

```
svg.selectAll("g").on("mouseout", function(){
    d3.select(this).lower()
});
```

The hover on Firefox is completly broken.
Any suggestions how to fix this problem?

Tested on `Chrome 87.0.4280.66` and `Firefox 83.0 (64-Bit)`

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n2b594dx/4/)

Comment: The `.raise()` and `.lower()` methods seem to work just fine; inspecting the DOM you'll notice that they are doing exactly what they are supposed to do. IMO, the real culprit is the `:hover` selector in FF. Searching for that one finds some problems reported using the selector on SVGs in FF. Just guessing, though. I suggest doing the entire event handling in D3 without the need for any styling using an external CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/hLgy72t3/ This works fine in both Chrome and FF.

Comment: Thats the trick. Thank you, please write a answer so that I can mark it as correct :)